# What does the C++ standard say about std::vector<int> v1,v2; std::distance(v1.begin(),v2.begin())?

Tags: c++, iterator, standards, language-lawyer, std

I have this code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<int> v1,v2;
   std::cout << std::distance(v1.begin(),v2.begin());
   return 0;
}
```

and it has a bug because it is not meaningful to compare the iterators of two different vectors.

I had a look at [N3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) at *24.4.4 Iterator operations* at page 815:

> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
> typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
> distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: If `InputIterator` meets the requirements of random access iterator, `last` shall be reachable from `first` or `first` shall be
>   reachable from `last`; otherwise, `last` shall be reachable from
>   `first`.

Now I think that *Requires* is not fulfilled.

What does the standard state should happen in this case?

Comment: If it isnt permitted by standard, it will most likely result in undefined behaviour, because it is kind of illogical to compare iterators of different vectors

Comment: In general, breaking a requirement gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[iterator.requirements.general]:

> An iterator `j` is called *reachable* from an iterator `i` if and only
>   if there is a finite sequence of applications of  the expression `++i`
>   that makes `i == j`.

The problem is that once you incremented `v1.begin()` `v1.size()-1` times, the next increment operation induces undefined behavior, so `v2.begin()` cannot be reached from `v1.begin()`. The same argument makes `v1.begin()` unreachable from `v2.begin()`.

---

In case your question was "What happens if a condition in a *Requires* section is violated?", look at [res.on.required]:

> Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s *Requires:*
>   paragraph results in undefined behavior unless the function’s *Throws:*
>   paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is
>   violated.

Answer (score 5):

In some implementations of `std::distance`, the first iterator is incremented until it reaches the second iterator.  The iterations are counted:

```
unsigned int counts = 0;
while (iter1 != iter2)
{
  ++counts;
  ++iter1;
}
```

If the iterators point to containers in different address spaces, the loop many not terminate.  Using the terms in the standard, the second iterator is not *reachable*.

Answer (score 3):

The `requires` is not met, which means the code has undefined behavior: Anything could happen.

Answer (score 3):

In this case will be undefined behavior. Because `last` is not reachable from `first` by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing `first`.